# XmlSerializer serialize empty/null string

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

How I Serialize Empty String / Null String.

Because right now it would serialize to element like this `<Element />`

Instead of that, I want it to be element like this `<Element></Element>`

Right now I use `StringWriter` to Serialize it to XML.

here's my code:

```
using (var sw = new Utf8StringWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, obj);
    string serializedContent = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `<Element />` and `<Element></Element>` is exactly the same in xml.

Comment: @Caramiriel well, they are *semantically equivalent*; the difference can usually be discerned by any reader API, though

Comment: is there any chance the reader would read it wrong because the element is not same?

Answer (score 2):

You can use XmlElement attribute and specify that value should be nullable. Then the empty element will be serialized with correct nil value.

For Example:

```
public class EmployeeDetail
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    //// ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also for the information - if you have class with 2 properties: 
`public decimal? Property1 {get;set;}
public string Property2 {get;set;}
`
and you have an object with `both` this properties = `null` for default: `Property1` will be serialized with `nil` value, but `Property2` will be `ignored` (not exists in result xml). I have spent quite a while before I found that I have to mark Property2 with `XmlElement(IsNullable = true)` attribute, even if it obvious that `string` could be null same as `decimal?` .

Answer (score 0):

hello I don't know your implementation but you might try to configure your serialiser with this option :

```cs
w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

it may do the same than customising the `XmlWriter`